# Ip address changes whenever I modified my location

Tags: command-line, 16.10, ip, hostname

Why each time I change of location the ip address is modified. In fact, today, I was in three different places during day, and each time I've execute the `hostname -I` command the ip address was different.

Comment: Each locations have different IPs whether internal or external. Different routers will have different IPs assigned for you computer. Unless you make it a static one which isn't going to work all the time if you move around a lot

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi So the Ip address assigns by `hostname -I` would be the one of the router. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the router dynamically assigns ips to hosts

Comment: This afternoon I was located in a cafe with two computers (VM and simple Linux OS). When I executed the previous command, I had two different ip addresses. Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, one is your computer's ip, the other is the vm. I have an openvpn server with 3 ips, 1 for server, 2 for udp and tcp ips

Comment: I think there's a contradiction. You said I was right when I explained `hostname -I` is the ip's router (where I'm located). So theoretically, the IPs assign to both machine should be the same. However, in your last comment, you said it is respectively the computer's ip and the vm's ip. Could you construct a full answer to explain that?

Comment: of course ip changes. that's how dynamic ip assignment works on each router.

Comment: I'm a bit confused actually. Could you explain a full answer to respond the question?

Comment: Sorry I thought you were referring to the ip assigned by the router. To find out the router's Ip you must execute `nm-tool | grep -i gateway | xargs echo | cut -d' ' -f2
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hostname -I` lists all assigned IP addresses on your host presently.  I have VMPlayer installed on my system, so I get three IP addresses listed.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ hostname -I
10.0.0.100 172.16.163.1 192.168.43.1
```

The first group of numbers `10.0.0.100` is my local IP address of my system given to me by my DHCP server / router.  The next two sets of numbers are assigned by the VMPlayer and are not controllable by the network manager of this host.

With DHCP servers, as long as your computer's local IP settings are set for `dynamic` no matter where you go and connect your IP address will change.  Most of this will be based on the DHCP Leases of each server.  If you connect to the same server within the Lease time of the IP address, you should obtain the exact same IP address again since the server assigns the IP addresses to the MAC address that is connected.  Once a Lease expires the DHCP server should reclaim that IP address and assign it to another system when it connects.

To get a little more in depth look at my present network, I use `netstat`.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
172.16.163.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmnet1
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmnet8
```

With `netstat`, the `-r` means to show me the routes, and the `-n` means to show me numeric instead of the hostnames.  In my example above, you can see that my network gateway is `10.0.0.1` which should be my router.

Answer (score 1):

Your IP address will change since if you are changing locations you are probably changing where/what you connect to the internet with.

Though this might help
http://whatismyipaddress.com/keeps-changing